# If $A$ and $B$ are diagonal and $C$ is a real symmetric matrix and $A=BC$, does $C$ need to be diagonal too?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

As the question above, if $A,B$ are square (complex) diagonal matrices and $C$ is square real symmetric and
$$
A=BC,
$$
Does this imply that $C$ must also be diagonal?

---

Some context: This arose in a physics problem where I started with complex square matricies $A’$ and $B’$ simultaneously diagonalisible in the same basis and $C’$ real diagonal, s.t. $A’=B’C’$. So my approach was that in the eigenbasis of $A’$ and $B’$ we get the above form and I got stuck. All I want to find is an expression for the eigenvalues of $A$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$ if that is possible.

---

Edit: $A$ and $B$ are invertible and thus non-zero.

Comment: If $A=B=0$, $C$ can be anything.

Comment: Are $A,B$ invertible ?

Comment: @Peter yes, $A$and $B$ are invertible.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $A$ and $B$ are not zero.

Comment: Hint : If $B$ is invertible, you have $C=B^{-1}A$ and $B^{-1}$ is a diagonal-matrix. What can you conclude ?

Comment: Where is that stated in the question?

Comment: Thanks @Peter I feel very silly now. Sorry José, I will add that.

Comment: @Peter so we can also conclude that the eigenvalues of $A’$, $a_n’$, are given by the product of eigenvalues of $B’$ and $C’$ Right? I.e. $a_n’=b_n’c_n’$

Comment: If the $b_n'$ are all non-zero (making $B'$ invertible) , then yes.